# How to run a powershell script in a GPO to change Windows administrator password?

Tags: powershell, samba, gpo

I have a domain with Samba 4. I use a workstation with Windows 10 and RSAT to administer it.

I want to create a GPO to change the Windows administrator user password.

Create the script below. Running it on a Windows 10 machine I was able to change the password. Then I created a GPO to be executed at the startup of the domain machines, but it didn't work.

**Script:**

```
# Save current execution policy
$currentExecutionPolicy = Get-ExecutionPolicy

# Temporarily disable execution policy (make it possible to run scripts)
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass

# Set the local Administrator user path
$computer = "."
$adminUser = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computer/Administrator,user"

# Set a new password that will be assigned to the local Administrator user
$newPassword = "mypassword"

# Attempting to change the local Administrator user password
try {
    $adminUser.SetPassword($newPassword)
    $adminUser.SetInfo()
    Write-Host "Local Administrator user password has been successfully changed!"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
} catch {
    Write-Host "An error occurred while changing the Administrator user password: $_"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    
}

# Restore the original execution policy
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy $currentExecutionPolicy
```

Comment: Having a plain text password in a script is never a good idea. Are you not able to use Microsoft LAPS in your environment?

Comment: Well, a GPO wil probably execute your script in a different context. When you tested your script manually, it worked for a specific user, probably an administrator. Besides that, if you change your password like that, then there is effectively no need to change it. Putting your admin password into a GPO is like sending it to every domain member via email. So consider it as compromised as the previous one.

Comment: Also, there is no point in changing the execution policy back and forth inside that script that already would need it. It does not help at all. Execution policies are for human users. If you call PowerShell programmatically, call it with `-ExecutionPolicy ByPass` and leave the current security settings as they are.

Comment: @KG-DROID I don't know Microsoft LAPS. 
I'll look for more information.

Comment: @stackprotector  I did an initial test with just a local machine and a single machine in the domain. But it is not safe to set the password in text form in a script. I'm giving up on this script. Is there a safer way to do this password change?

Comment: LAPS is the safe way, and allows for unique passwords per device.